# shell_exec doesn't show the tilde value in php

Tags: php, shell-exec

On my remote server, i can use this instruction

```
$home = `echo ~`;
```

it works fine

but on my local-based website, this same instruction doesn't give anything ..
I disabled the safe_mode, i looked into the disable function (shell_exec is not disabled).

a little rod in the wheel that prevents me from going anywhere more further in my development ..

**note**: both server run on Unix system

Comment: what os is your local-based website use?

Comment: Enable the error_reporting, and check the error.